# Why is i2cset giving "resource busy" on my BeagleBone Black?

Tags: i2c, beaglebone-black

After trying to get Adafruit's 8x8 LED Matrix python example code to work on both my Raspberry Pi and my BeagleBone Black, I realized there is probably something wrong with Adafruit's code and not me.  The matrix is working just fine with a Teensy3.1.

I decided that this is a good time to cut my losses and learn how to program i2c.

In my first steps I came across this useful [blog](http://emalliab.wordpress.com/2013/07/20/adafruit-8x8-backpack-ht16k33-rpi/) where someone did this using the i2cset command.  Unfortunately the device seems busy.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

According to one person,  "UU" on the i2cdetect, could mean "Probing was skipped, because this address is currently in use by a driver".

Others had also mentioned "modules" that may already be using the i2c bus, and that one could remove these "modules" and try again.

Comment: Something that might be worth a try if you haven't already is removing the device and try the `i2cdetect` again, the last time I had a similar problem it was because the device was on a different bus / address to what the docs indicated so I was trying to access something else. It might be worth trying an `i2cset -f` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It ended up being the second i2c bus that I needed to use.  As you can see below, 0x70 is the "chip address" available on bus 2!  UU is signifying something unavailable or busy.

[image]

After this I was able to follow the nice instructions [here](http://emalliab.wordpress.com/2013/07/20/adafruit-8x8-backpack-ht16k33-rpi/), but using bus 2.

Specifically,

```
i2cset -y 2 0×70 0×21

i2cset -y 2 0×70 0×81

i2cset -y 2 0×70 0xe0
```

for starting the multiplexing oscillator, enabling the display with no blink, and brightness

Using this information I was actually able to modify Adafruit's code for `matrix8x8_test.py` example, explicitly defining the i2c bus and chip address `display = Matrix8x8.Matrix8x8(address=0x70, busnum=2)`.  This is on a BeagleBone Black wired exactly as Adafruit said.  I hope this helps someone.  I will definitely be learning the i2c bus inferface myself as it's going to be worth it in the future when stuff like this comes up.